# How do I sell a typeface I've made?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone have experience selling a typeface they've made? What are some foundries that buy from individuals? Any advice? Asking price? It's a full set of glyphs with some ligatures. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyFonts is the big hitter in the small foundry / individual designer arena. Check out the ['How to sell your fonts'](http://www.myfonts.com/info/prospectus/) page.

Look around their site and see how comparable fonts are priced. It's hard to say without seeing the style of the font and the level of drawing/programming quality. That said, $29 - $59 is a normal range for a single font.

> **Submitting your work**
>
> Foundries or individuals wanting to sign up should send the following to signup@myfonts.com:
>
> - A short text (50-100 words) presenting yourself and/or the foundry.
>   This text is for internal use, once accepted you can submit a new text
>   for public use.
> - Finished font files of the typefaces you wish to
>   propose. You can submit up to 10 type families, but 1 will also do.
>   The typical number of first-time font submissions is 1 to 3 families
>   or single fonts. Your files will exclusively be used for review until
>   your foundry is accepted and an agreement signed. As a rule, new fonts
>   are released in OTF and/or TTF OpenType formats.
> - Not mandatory, but it
>   can be helpful: A short descriptive text (10-50 words) about each font
>   family.